# Filter an array based on density

Tags: php, python, arrays, algorithm, filter

I have a sample graph like one below.., which I plotted with set of (x,y) values in an array X.

http://bubblebird.com/images/t.png

***As you can see the image has dense peak values between 4000 to 5100***

My exact question is can I programmatically find this range where the graph is most dense?

ie.. **with Array X how can I find range within which this graph is dense?**
for this array it would be 4000 - 5100.

Assume that the array has only one dense region for simplicity.

Thankful if you can suggest a pseudocode/code.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the largest `Y` differences where the `X` advancement is the smallest? Although I must admit, that this looks like some type of homework ...

Comment: Am I the only one who can't see the image?

Comment: @Neowizard: i see it fine...

Comment: @Dainis: But as you can see in the graph around **x=300** there is sudden jump of y value with least x advancement.. but its a thin region.

Comment: @everlasto Well... then just calculate it over a longer period of `X`. Meaning. Find the point with sudden burst and summ them up till you get to `x = 500` or so.

Comment: yeah got it a bit and modified a little..  find a sudden burst point, from there check if 'y' is above some threshold value and if suddenly 'y' value drops then mark it as end of that region. So we would get 6-7 such regions for this graph and region with highest width will be the desired one. Let me try it programmatically :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the variance of the signal on a moving window.
Here is an example (see the graph attached where the test signal is red, the windowed variance is green and the filtered signal is blue) :

[image: simple example] :

test signal generation :

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(200) - 100.  
Y = (np.exp(-(X/10)**2) + np.exp(-((np.abs(X)-50.)/2)**2)/3.) * np.cos(X * 10.)
```

compute moving window variance :

```
window_length = 30 # number of point for the window
variance = np.array([np.var(Y[i-window_length / 2.: i+window_length/2.]) for i in range(200)])
```

get the indices where the variance is high (here I choose the criterion variance superior to half of the maximum variance... you can adapt it to your case) :

```
idx = np.where(variance > 0.5 * np.max(variance))

X_min = np.min(X[idx])
# -14.0
X_max = np.max(X[idx])
# 15.0
```

or filter the signal (set to zero the points with low variance)

```
Y_modified = np.where(variance > 0.5 * np.max(variance), Y, 0)
```

Comment: Works great.. I tried changing `variance = np.array([np.var(Y[i-window_length / 2.: i+window_length/2.]) for i in range(200)])` to `variance = np.array([np.var(Y[i-window_length : i+window_length/2.]) for i in range(200)])` and output is still refined.

Comment: It means you changed your window length (now your actual length will be 3./2.*window_length instead of just window_length) but also you decided to have a window which is not centered... why? If you plot your variance it will be shifted to the left

Comment: Forget that.. Btw In my graph, note **there are two sudden impulses before x=1000** that would affect variance isn't??.. So instead of getting X_min around 4000, I would get X_min very earlier. X_max is fine anyways.. But when i slice the array so that it starts with X=2000, I'm getting X_min as desired. .. ..??

Comment: The thing with those impulses is that even if they are strong, they are very localized. So if your window is long enough it should works just fine because the variance is the average of the distances to the mean value, meaning if you have a window where your values are 0 all the way except for a strong value at one point (let say 10.) the mean value will be almost 0, then the distance vector (vector composed by value - mean value ) will be zeros except for 10 at one point... so the mean of that distance vector (the actual variance) will be almost 0!

Comment: That is why this method of windowed variance is really testing the density of the peaks! Not only their strength! One strong peak really localized will be filtered while a lot of peaks even if they are not that strong will be kept! I'm not sure my explanation is very clear... let me know if you didn't understand!

Answer (score 4):

you may calculate the absolute difference between the adjacent values, then maybe smooth things a little with sliding window and then find the regions, where the smoothed absolute difference values are at 50% of maximum value.

using python (you have python in tags) this would look like this:

```
a = ( 10, 11, 9, 10, 18, 5, 20, 6, 15, 10, 9, 11 )

diffs = [abs(i[0]-i[1]) for i in zip(a,a[1:])]
# [1, 2, 1, 8, 13, 15, 14, 9, 5, 1, 2]
maximum = max(diffs)
# 15
result = [i>maximum/2 for i in diffs]
# [False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Yeah.. I tried and got a graph like one below.. where yellow regions denote "true"... and now I can easily find my way through.. Thank you @lenik!!! [http://bubblebird.com/images/k.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use classification algorithm (for example k-means), to split data into clusters and find the most weighted cluster